# Javascript syntax for self invoking function with async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, arrow-functions

In JS in can write a self invoking arrow function with async like this:

```
(async () => {
    const promis = fetch(uri);
    console.log(await promis);
})();
```

A self invoking function without parameters I could also write like this:

```
{
   // do something
}
```

I was asking myself, is there a syntax to combine both and do something like this or is the first example already the shortest form?

```
// this is not working
async {
   const promis = fetch(uri);
   console.log(await promis);
}
```

Comment: Your second snippet is not a self invoking function without parameters, it's just a block. For instance, a var declaration won't be scoped inside of your second example

Comment: `async` attributes a function, so the initial syntax is as terse as it can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Javascript syntax, `async` is a modifier of a function.  So, the only thing that can be `async` is a function.

Your second section of code is merely a block.  It doesn't create a new function or a new function scope.  And, per the Javascript syntax, you can't use `async` with a block.  For example a variable declared in that block with `var` would still be hoisted to the top of the containing function scope because that doesn't create a new function scope.

Your third section of code does not work because `async` only works with functions, not with blocks (per the Javascript specification).

If you want an inline `async` section of code, you have to declare and execute a function and your first code block is a compact way to do that.  You have to have a function, not just a block.

Answer (score 8):

two way, we just can short a little :)

1. simple way

```js
!async function () {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
}();
```

or like yours

```js
(async  () => {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
})();

//maybe this is better then above
;(async function () {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
}());

//this is allmost same
;[ async function () {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
}()];
```

2. use [then] this is not absolute "anonymous"

```js
var x=async  () => 100;

x().then(
    e=>console.log({e})
);
```

Comment: What's the name of the syntax in your simple example? I haven't come across that before.

Comment: function expression, the [!] means that not only definition, that is an expression. expression means some thing that can be run, and that need to be a value.  other way, we can call it: closure, or: IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. A `block statement` only creates a new scope, just like an IIFE. An `async function` however is executed *asynchronously*, that can't be done with a block.

Comment: Saying an async function isn't executed asynchronously is kind of misleading.  When you call an async function, it is executed synchronously (up to the first `await`) and then returns a promise.  In fact, if there's no `await` in it, it's executed entirely synchronously.